# Spring with IntelliJ attribute p:prefix is not allowed here

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

Please help I need to surpass this problem:
[image]
I have no idea of how to solve this problem.

Snippet of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/p ">


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="basic" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>

</beans>
```

Now for the second try:
[image]

Comment: Please upload your project on `github` or somewhere, I am gonna solve it now

Comment: I have some problems with GIT, so to don't keep you waiting I had uploaded the project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gukNHlNLpHQYy_AEbo2TDGElixZmNUwK/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                                            And thanks for the help

Comment: Can't solve the issue. It's probably the problem of `intelliJ`. You should learn `maven`. Always use IDE to write code and use terminal to compile code.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/p ">


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="basic" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView" >
        <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I had copied and paste your code, but I still have the same problem with prefix and suffix. I don't see where is the button to upload a new photo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the wrong class in the bean.

It is not "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView"

It is ""org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"